# Select in regex the first sentece after question mark

Tags: regex

I need to select with regex the first sentence (all text to the first dot) of each question. And then in repleace I add **$1** to put this tag

I try this but select whole text, not only the first sentence.

`^[a-zA-Z].*`

I have an example:

> Cómo se hace para formatear una PC? Haz click sobre el botón de
> inicio. Selecciona la rueda dentada para acceder a Ajustes del
> Sistema. Pulsa sobre Actualización y Seguridad. En la pestaña de
> Restaurar, haz click en Comenzar o Empezar. En la ventana que se abre,
> selecciona Restablecer Ajustes de Fábrica.
>
> ¿Cómo formatear mi PC windows 10 a estado de fábrica? Haz click sobre
> el botón de inicio. Selecciona la rueda dentada para acceder a Ajustes
> del Sistema. Pulsa sobre Actualización y Seguridad. En la pestaña de
> Restaurar, haz click en Comenzar o Empezar. En la ventana que se abre,
> selecciona Restablecer Ajustes de Fábrica.

And this is what I need.

> Cómo se hace para formatear una PC?
> **Haz click sobre el botón de inicio.** Selecciona la rueda dentada para acceder a Ajustes del Sistema. Pulsa sobre Actualización y Seguridad. En la pestaña de Restaurar, haz click en Comenzar o Empezar. En la ventana que se abre, selecciona Restablecer Ajustes de Fábrica.
> ¿Cómo formatear mi PC windows 10 a estado de fábrica?
> **Haz click sobre el botón de inicio.** Selecciona la rueda dentada para acceder a Ajustes del Sistema. Pulsa sobre Actualización y Seguridad. En la pestaña de Restaurar, haz click en Comenzar o Empezar. En la ventana que se abre, selecciona Restablecer Ajustes de Fábrica.

I try a lot of features but I'm so bad with regex and I couldn't select that.

Comment: What tool/language are you using? Are you aware of abbreviations that can occure in natural language text such as `Mr.`, `E.g.`. `I.e.`... would that be an issue? Is it right that you want to match from the first question mark `?` until the first dot and make this part bold?

Comment: im using sublimetext/notepad ++ to do that. With my regex: ^[a-zA-Z].* i select all text betweet questions but i need to stop on the first dot.

Comment: Try [replace `(^[^?]*\?\s*)([^.]+\.)` with `$1<b>$2</b>`](https://regex101.com/r/APTKqR/1) (not so clear) or to just match the sentence part with NP++ e.g.: [`^[^?]*\??\s*\K[^.]+\.`](https://regex101.com/r/sh3c4S/1)

Comment: No, it works fine, it select all text and then replace the question too. thank you.

Comment: With the [second regex](https://regex101.com/r/sh3c4S/1) you'd need to replace with [`<b>$0</b>`](https://regex101.com/r/mvbTGL/1). This one would only work with Notepad++ I guess.

Comment: i need another question, if i have this text: "como estas?", how can i select this question and add with replace ¿ before? final: ¿Como estas?. Best regards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249084/discussion-between-regue-and-bobble-bubble).

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern `(?<=\? )[^\.]*` - see [here](https://regex101.com/r/WvUibk/1) for a breakdown of the RegEx.

If you also need to capture the period at the end of the sentence, use this: `(?<=\? )[^\.]*\.` (note the addition of `\.` at the end)

Comment: it works the selection but when i try to replace with <b>$1</b> it doesnt replace, only put <b></b> and delete text.

Comment: Try adding parentheses surrounding the `[^\.]*` part to form a capture group, e.g.: `(?<=\? )([^\.]*)`, *or* simply use `$0` instead of `$1`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this pattern, this won't include the question mark and dot, and uses lazy to only put bold marks around the first sentence:

```
Replace(r"(?<=\?)(.*?)(?<=\.)","<b>\1<b>")
```